# I upgraded to Windows 10, screen resolution not proper

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I have monitor Dell IN2030M. After upgrading to Windows 10, from the available screen resolutions, I am not getting proper one.

Few are too small, few too big, all the text looks either stretched or shrinked. Suggest me what should I do to set a proper screen resolution.

Comment: Have you check to see if there are updated drivers for that monitor and/or your graphics card? When I upgraded mine, Windows 10 chose a generic Microsoft driver over the manufacturer's which had been previously loaded.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and couldn't find a driver, and then after about an hour and another reboot, the problem went away. So make sure to try another reboot after some time.